# Does my code produce a pseudorandom or random number?

Tags: python, random

```
import time

point1 = time.time()

point2 = time.time()

point3 = time.time()

random_number = str((point1 + point2 - point3) * point1)

print(random_number[7])
print(random_number[8])
print(random_number[9])
print(random_number[10])
```

It was my homework to design an algorithm that prodeces pseudorandom numbers. Would the above code be concidered to be pseudorandom? I am  assuming it could be called that because the number outcome is unpredictable but i just wanted to make sure. Also, how do i print all the numbers on the same line?
When i do `print(random_number[10][7][8][9])`, i get an error. I dont want to print out all the numbers because the first few are almost always the same. Thanks for helping.

Comment: `print(random_number[7], random_number[8], random_number[9], random_number[10])` or `print(random_number[7:11])`

Comment: Pseudorandom because, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness) "A pseudorandom process produces predictable outcomes given information which is typically difficult to acquire; absent such information, pseudorandom sequences of numbers exhibit statistical randomness." If you want to print what's in your `random_number` variable just print it.

Comment: Alright, solved my problem, thanks

Comment: There are many well-known algorithms for producing pseudo-random numbers, and your program doesn't use any of them. True randomness is very difficult to obtain with a computer and will necessitate calling something external to your program.

Comment: The `IndexError` is because you've tried to access a 4D structure, which you do not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would definetly call those pseudorandom, there is no randomizing involved, because you are just using a clock, which is definetly predictable, although it's hard to predict the microseconds on execution.

Depending on the time your last digits might be 0 and get stripped, that's the reason why you are running into an `IndexError` exception.

Comment: Doesn't most native random number functions use the machines internal clock?

Comment: yes, RNGs invoke the clock, but it's not the only source.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is "no": you have not produced either random or pseudo-random numbers.  Search on line for "random number generation" ... which you should have done before writing your program, let alone posting here.

The three "point" variables are highly dependent on one another; for all practical purposes, you've taken the present time in seconds, cubed it, and extracted four consecutive digits from the product.  Since the digits of cubes are not "nicely" distributed, you should find that your do not have a uniform distribution over the ten digits, let alone a pseudo-random sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code does not read from any physical source of randomness (a reverse-biased diode, Geiger counter, weather patterns, a lava lamp), it is the result of a deterministic process, and therefore is at best pseudo-random. Because the process you chose has no mathematical foundation to explain its distribution or other properties, it is likely to be not pseudo-random either, or very weakly pseudo-random.